# Work with matrix (I can't edit visualisation)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have this table in Power BI, But I can't do another table.
[image: 1]

How I can do this?

Now the values are grouped by date (different fields have information under one date, next the same fields are grouped by another date)
I want the values in the columns to be grouped by field (one field has date information next to it).

Edit1:
I can't set Date on the 2nd place in the grouping

[image: 2]

Because date is column, traffic,orders,rev,costs- are values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set Date on the 2nd place in the grouping, after a field containing *traffic*, *orders*, etc.

**EDIT:**

You need to unpivot these columns first, for example, in PowerQuery. Use *Edit Query*. This results in transforming your 4 columns to 2: Attribute and Value. Attribute will be your first grouping parameter. 2nd will be `Date`. `Value` column goes to values.

If you need your source query somewhere else, you may create new query for this very report only. It is done by first right-clicking original one and selecting *Reference Query*, and the doing any edits. This will keep original query intact.

Comment: Add edit1 in question with picture. I can not put the field on another level, as for example in Excel.

Comment: @Zzema changed the answer, have a look.

Comment: O, thanks. It's resolved some problems. But how I can change my measures, For example, AOV = revenue / orders OR Prev_Traffic = CALCULATE(SUM(DailyMedium[traffic]); PREVIOUSMONTH('Calendar'[Date]))

Comment: @Zzema, you should change attribute name (traffic, cost etc.) in your measures to [Value]:
= CALCULATE(SUM(DailyMedium[Value]); PREVIOUSMONTH('Calendar'[Date]))
and, if necessary, add filter to raw measures, like 
Revenue = CALCULATE(SUM(DailyMedium[Value]);DailyMedium[Attribute]="Revenue")

Comment: @MaxZelensky for Prev_Traffic it helps me, thanks. But what about AOV = revenue / orders - I can not change from measure to value, since AOV should be calculated after the aggregation of the values

Comment: @Zzema, can't catch your problem. Nominator and denominator are measures?

Comment: @MaxZelensky No, it's values.
I have a table:

Comment: @MaxZelensky
I have a table: date/orders/revenue: 01.01.2001/2/20000. This table consists many dates in rows. If I calculate AOV for 1 row it's a 10000. But If I use matrix and want to calculate AOV for all month, I must use a measure. Because I can't use column (AOV_month)<>avg(AOV_date). Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: @Zzema no problem. You can write a [Revenue] measure as it described few comments above. Then write [Count of  Orders] measure same way, just change attribute filter for = "orders".

Comment: @Zzema then your AOV measure will be like =DIVIDE ([Revenue], [Count of Orders])